# Passing data between directives and controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm just working on a projet in Angular 1. The task is to do a DOM tree from json object and manipulate with it through native drag'n'drop DOM operations **(with out jQuery and etc)**. I've been done parsing json-> dom function, loading json from server, some drag'n'drop event handlers. Now my question is how to update a json object (from this object I get a ul>li tree structure) when I done a DROP event.
Now, code

> View

```
<div ng-controller="TreeController">
        <ng-dom-tree 
            style="background-color: #000" 
            ng-model = "treeJson"
            class="tree" 
            ng-draggable 
            ng-droppable>
        </ng-dom-tree>
</div>
```

> Controller

```
.controller('TreeController', TreeController);

TreeController.$inject = ['treeService', '$scope'];

function TreeController(treeService, $scope) {

    $scope.treeJson = '';
    treeService.getTree().success(function (data) {
        $scope.treeJson = data;
    });
}
```

> Main directive

```
.directive('ngDomTree', ngDomTree)
ngDomTree.$inject = [];
function ngDomTree() {
    var isEmpty = function (object) {
        for (var key in object) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
    function createTree(tree, list) { /*creating tree -> json to dom*/}
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, elt, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('treeJson', function (data) {
                if (isEmpty(data))
                    return;
                **CAN'T HANDLE DATA CHANGING HERE**
                elt.append(document.createElement('ul'));
                createTree(data, document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]);
            });

        }
    }
}
```

> Sup directive

```
.directive('ngDroppable', ngDroppable)
ngDroppable.$inject = [];
function ngDroppable() {
    var parseTreeToJson = function(tree){/* dom to json */}
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elt, attrs) {
            elt.on('mouseover', function (e) {

                var droppableElt = e.target || event.target;
                if (!droppableElt.classList.contains('tree__node') && !droppableElt.classList.contains('tree__branch'))
                    return;

                droppableElt.addEventListener(
                    'dragover',
                    function (e) {

                        this.classList.add('navigator');
                        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
                        if (e.preventDefault)
                            e.preventDefault();
                        this.classList.add('over');
                        return false;
                    },
                    false
                );

                droppableElt.addEventListener(
                    'dragenter',
                    function (e) {
                        this.classList.add('over');
                        return false;
                    },
                    false
                );

                droppableElt.addEventListener(
                    'dragleave',
                    function (e) {
                        this.classList.remove('over');
                        this.classList.remove('navigator');
                        return false;
                    },
                    false
                );

                droppableElt.addEventListener(
                    'drop',
                    function (e) {

                        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
                        this.classList.remove('over');
                        let item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));

                        this.appendChild(item);
                        item.id = '';
                        //updating here
                        scope.treeJson = parseTreeToJson(elt[0].children[0]); 

                        return false;
                    },
                    false
                );
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So, In Sup directive when **drop** event created, and I'm reinit **treeJson** variable, after that I need in main directive reinitializing the tree and also in controller get new json structure from this variable, because $watch is used, but it isn't happened.

PLEASE HELP

THNKS FOR ATTENTION :)

P.S.  [Here it is in Plnkr.co](http://embed.plnkr.co/Y6EnAIyxxXaeUA0eoOKL/)

Comment: Hi Ethan, Can u give us plunker so that we can dig bit more?

Comment: @user3249448 [Here](http://embed.plnkr.co/Y6EnAIyxxXaeUA0eoOKL/)

Comment: I didn't mention it in my answer, but your `ngDroppable` directive has a pretty serious flaw due to how it binds events (in that 1. It doesn't bind the events to relevant elements when they are needed, and 2. It will bind up to infinite handlers to each element). I assume you know this, but just in case you don't (or don't know a solution), look into event delegation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using native DOM, it bypasses angular's processors. You need to call [scope.$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) after changing angular's state to tell it that something changed.

```
droppableElt.addEventListener(
    'drop',
    function (e) {

        if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
        this.classList.remove('over');
        let item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
        this.appendChild(item);
        item.id = '';
        scope.treeJson = parseTreeToDOM(elt[0].children[0]);
        scope.$digest();
    },
    false
);
```